# Why is assigning a PHP variable printing a value out on the screen?

Tags: php

This has me completely baffled, I'm doing the following:

```
if($tasks = someFunction(1))
{


}
```

someFunction() returns an array of records from a database. For some reason, assigning this array to $tasks causes a number to be printed out to the screen. The number it prints is the number of records that it has returned, but at no point do I ever echo this variable.

To confirm, I added the following code:

```
$tasks = someFunction(1);
$tasks = someFunction(1);
$tasks = someFunction(1);
```

Above the if statement, and sure enough I was greeted by "4444" on my screen (It was returning 4 records). I've implemented code that's basically identical elsewhere in my code and have never run into this, I'm confused as to how a variable assignment can cause a value to display on the screen.

Comment: What are the contents of someFunction() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely outputting a number from inside the `someFunction()` method.

Try doing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac) to *find text* and search for `echo` or `print` to find the occurence.

Comment: I feel foolish for making that problem way harder than it needed to be. When I actually looked properly at the code inside someFunction(), there it was starting me right in the face "echo $numRows", leftover debugging code. I do have a tendency to make things more complicated than they need to be, thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `someFunction()` is echoing/printing a value. If you simply want to retrieve the value of `someFunction()`, use the `return` statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Example: (returns `Success!`)

```
function someFunction()
{
    return "fish";
}

$tasks = "fish";
if ($tasks == someFunction())
{
    echo "Success!";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}
```